# add element to existing array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 39
        [countNew] => 0
        [nume] => Ardeleanu
    ) )
```

How can I add a new field in the existing array so it will look like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 39
        [countNew] => 0
        [nume] => Ardeleanu
        [migr] => 0
    ) )
```

I tryed array push but I get something like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 39
        [countNew] => 0
        [nume] => Ardeleanu
        [0] => Array
            (
                [migr] => 0
            )

    ) )
```

Comment: `$foo[0]['migr'] = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Justr try with:

```
$input = array(/* your data */);
$input[0]['migr'] = 0;
```

Or:

```
$input = array(/* your data */);
$additional = array('migr' => 0);

$input[0] = array_merge($input[0], $additional);
```